# Server in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, socket, server

I'm looking for a code review and code improvement for my own small server.
The server accepts the requests:
User Join,User Leave,User Text Notify Group Join, Group Leave, Group Notify Request Time.
The syntax for User Join/Left Group Join/Left:
**

```
DSLP-3.0
User Join
NameOfUser
DSLP-Body
```

**
The syntax for Group Notify:
**

```
DSLP-3.0
Group Notify
NameOfGroup
1(<--number of lines you want to send)
DSLP-Body
LineYouWantSend
```

**
The syntax for User Text Notify:
**

```
DSLP-3.0
User Text Notify
User1
User2
1(<---number of lines you want to send)
DSLP-Body
LineYouWantSend
```

**

The syntax for Request Time:

```
DSLP-3.0
Request Time
DSLP-Body
```

This is the code:

```
import socket
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime





host="localhost"
port=44444
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SOCK_STREAM
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

trash=[]
user=["foobar"]
group=["foobar"]
def clientHandler():
    platz=""
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ("Connected with", addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(4096)

        #error
        if repr(data)!="b'dslp-3.0'":
            print(error_firstline())
        else:
            while True:

                data = conn.recv(4096)
                platz+=repr(data)
                platz+="\r\n"
                trash.append(platz)

                if len(trash)==2 and platz.count("\r\n")==2:
                    if "b'dslp-3.0'" in platz:
                        continue
                    else:
                        print(error_search_2nd_line(platz))

                if len(trash)>4 and "b'dslp-3.0'" in platz:
                    pp=platz.rsplit("b'dslp-3.0'\r\n")
                    trash.clear()
                    print(error_search_2nd_line(pp[1]))

                if len(trash)>6:
                    trash.clear()


                if "request time" in platz:
                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        platz=check_dslp(platz)
                        print(response_time())
                        platz=""
                    if len(platz)>31:
                        print(error_forthline())

                if "group join" in platz:

                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        platz=check_dslp(platz)
                        so=platz.split(("b'group join'"))
                        soo=so[1].split(("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n"))
                        sooo=soo[0].split(("\r\nb'"))
                        zahl=len(platz)-len(sooo[1])

                        if zahl>33:
                            print(error_forthline())
                            platz=""
                        else:
                            print(group_join(platz))
                            platz=""


                if "group leave" in platz:

                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        platz=check_dslp(platz)
                        so=platz.split(("b'group leave'"))
                        soo=so[1].split(("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n"))
                        sooo=soo[0].split(("\r\nb'"))
                        zahl=len(platz)-len(sooo[1])

                        if zahl>34:
                            print(error_forthline())
                            platz=""
                        else:
                            print(group_leave(platz))
                            platz=""

                if "user join" in platz:
                    if len(trash)>4:
                        trash.clear()
                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        platz=check_dslp(platz)
                        so=platz.split(("b'user join'"))
                        soo=so[1].split(("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n"))
                        sooo=soo[0].split(("\r\nb'"))
                        zahl=len(platz)-len(sooo[1])

                        if zahl>32:
                            print(error_forthline())
                            platz=""
                        else:
                            print(user_join(platz))
                            platz=""

                if "user leave" in platz:
                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        platz=check_dslp(platz)
                        so=platz.split(("b'user leave'"))
                        soo=so[1].split(("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n"))
                        sooo=soo[0].split(("\r\nb'"))
                        zahl=len(platz)-len(sooo[1])
                        if zahl>33:
                            print(error_forthline())
                            platz=""
                        else:
                            print(user_leave(platz))
                            platz=""

                if "group notify" in platz:
                    platz=check_dslp(platz)
                    for i in range(5):
                        if str(i) in platz:

                            if i==1:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==5:

                                    print(group_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==2:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==6:
                                    print(group_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==3:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==7:
                                    print(group_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==4:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==8:
                                    print(group_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==5:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==9:
                                    print(group_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""

                if "user text notify" in platz:
                    platz=check_dslp(platz)
                    for i in range(5):
                        if str(i) in platz:

                            if i==1:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==6:
                                    print(user_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==2:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==7:
                                    print(user_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==3:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==8:
                                    print(user_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==4:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==9:
                                    print(user_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""
                            if i==5:
                                if platz.count("\r\n")==10:
                                    print(user_notify(platz))
                                    platz=""

                if "user list" in platz:
                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        print(user_list())
                        platz=""
                if "group list" in platz:
                    if "dslp-body" in platz:
                        print(group_list())
                        platz=""








for i in range(5):
    Thread(target=clientHandler).start()

s.close()

def error_search_2nd_line(platzhalter):

    bb=platzhalter.rsplit("b'")
    b=bb[1].rsplit("'\r\n")
    platzhalter=b[0]
    print (platzhalter)
    liste=["group join", "group leave", "user join", "user leave", "group notify", "user text notify","user list","group list"]
    bedingung=""
    for x in range(len(liste)):
        bedingung+=liste[x]
        if x+1==len(liste):
            if platzhalter not in bedingung:
                trash.clear()
                print(error_secondline())
            else:
                trash.clear()



def error_firstline():
    print("dslp-3.0\r\nerror\r\n1\r\ndslp-body\r\nReceived unexpected text as first line.\r\nConnection closed by foreign host.")

def error_secondline():
    print("error")
    print("1")
    print("dslp-body")
    print("Received unexpected message type in second line.")
    print("Connection closed by foreign host.")

def error_forthline():
    print("dslp-3.0")
    print("error")
    print("1")
    print("dslp-body")
    print("Unexpected state while analyzing line 4.")
    print("Connection closed by foreign host.")

def group_error():
    print("Group is unknown.")

def user_error():
    print("Source user is unknown.")

def check_dslp(platz):
    if "b'dslp-3.0'\r\n" in platz:
        pp=platz.rsplit("b'dslp-3.0'\r\n")
        platz=pp[1]
        return platz
    else:
        return platz





def group_join(platzhalter):
    print("dslp-3.0")
    print("group join ack")
    y=platzhalter.split("b'group join'\r\nb'")
    y=y[1].split("'")
    group.append(y[0])
    print(y[0])
    print("dslp-body")


def group_notify(platzhalter):
    if len(group)==1:
        print(group_error())
    for x in group:
        if x in platzhalter:
            pp=platzhalter.rsplit("dslp-body'\r\nb'")
            ppp=pp[1].rsplit("'\r\n")
            for i in ppp:
                print (i)
            break
        if x=="foobar":
            continue
        elif x not in platzhalter:
            print(group_error())




def group_leave(platzhalter):
    y=platzhalter.split("b'group leave'\r\nb'")
    y=y[1].split("'")
    for x in group:
        if y[0] in group:
            print("dslp-3.0")
            print("group leave ack")
            print(y[0])
            print("dslp-body")
            group.remove(y[0])
            break
        else:
            print(group_error())

def group_list():
    print("Groups: ")
    for i in group:
        print(i)

def user_join(platzhalter):
    if "b'dslp-3.0'\r\n" in platzhalter:
        z=platzhalter.split("b'dslp-3.0'\r\n")
        y=z[1]
        y=platzhalter.split("b'user join'\r\nb'")
        y=y[1].split("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n")
        y=y[0].split("'")
        user.append(y[0])
        print("dslp-3.0")
        print("user join ack")
        print(y[0])
        print("dslp-body")
    else:
        y=platzhalter.split("b'user join'\r\nb'")
        y=y[1].split("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n")
        y=y[0].split("'")
        user.append(y[0])
        print("dslp-3.0")
        print("user join ack")
        print(y[0])
        print("dslp-body")

def user_notify(platzhalter):
    if len(user)==1:
        print(user_error())
    for x in user:
        if x in platzhalter:
            pp=platzhalter.rsplit("dslp-body'\r\nb'")
            ppp=pp[1].rsplit("'\r\n")
            for i in ppp:
                print(i)
            break

        if x not in platzhalter:
            print(user_error())


def user_leave(platzhalter):
    y=platzhalter.split("b'user leave'\r\nb'")
    y=y[1].split("\r\nb'dslp-body'\r\n")
    y=y[0].split("'")
    user.remove(y[0])
    print("dslp-3.0")
    print("user leave ack")
    print(y[0])
    print("dslp-body")

def user_list():
    print("Users are: ")
    for i in user:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Packet fragmentation

```
    data = conn.recv(4096)

    #error
    if repr(data)!="b'dslp-3.0'":
```

To quote the documentation for [`recv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv),

> The **maximum** amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize.

Emphasis mine. This is a common pitfall that beginners encounter when attempting low-level socket programming. The socket library gives you no guarantee that you will actually get 4096 bytes, or even a complete message. You need to iterate until you think you have enough bytes or a valid message, however you define that.

Put another way, it would be trivially easy to write a client that sends fragmented data to your server that *should* be valid but will in fact be erroneously rejected.

Though I haven't tried it, [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.StreamRequestHandler) seems like its `rfile` should be able to abstract this away for you since it handles buffering. In other words, you don't need to worry about packets or buffer sizes; you can ask for `rfile.readline()`, which is what you actually want given your protocol.

If you do not want the abstraction of `socketserver`, you can also use [`makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) - which is called by `socketserver` anyway.